# MongoDB db.copyDatabase fail on unauthorized

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to copy between two different DBs on MongoLab using the mongo CLI.
I followed the docs - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/

1. Connected to the target DB.
2. Ran the following:

   db.copyDatabase('source-db', 'target-db', 'source-host', 'source-user', 'source-pwd')

But I always getting:

```
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" }
```

Comment: Are you on a shared plan? I don't think you can `copyDatabase()` to a shared destination database there.

Comment: both side are non-shared

Comment: Then no, I have no idea, only have a shared plan to test with :)

Comment: silly question: did you auth to the database with username that has appropriate permissions to run this command?

Comment: MongoLab has two options User and Read-Only User. How can IC check the permissions?

Comment: It seems this command is not adopted to the newer auth model so if you have old styled users will work otherway not. There is a sidenote in the sources at least about that but i am quite sure. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/cloner.cppIn line 704 "Note: doesn't work with authentication enabled, except as old-style users."
If i am right.

Comment: Check this : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8213

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am getting the same error, but when trying to copy a collection:

```
> db.coll1.copyTo("coll2");
Wed Jul 24 13:32:05 uncaught exception: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" }
```

My database is on a shared server managed by MongoHQ, so there definitely might be some permission problem there that the service does not allow `copyTo` or other commands to run.

A simple workaround is to manually fetch all the objects in the collection and insert them to the second collection. This is how things were done prior to `copyTo` being implemented:

```
db.coll1.find().forEach(function(o) { db.coll2.insert(o); });
```

Comment: yes, this is how I solved it, but I don't think it's the most efficient way.

Comment: Not efficient, true, but gets the job done. And that's what counts :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use mongodump and mongorestore commands instead.

```
mongodump -h <source_host>:<source_port> -d <source_db> -o ~/tmp/mongodump

mongorestore -h <destination_host>:<destination_port> -d <destination_db> -u <username> -p <password> ~/tmp/mongodump/<source_db>
```