# mongodb returns unauthorized on copydatabase

Tags: mongodb

I am logged with a user that has readWriteAnyDatabase, dbAdminAnyDatabase, userAdminAnyDatabase, clusterAdmin but still can not copy database. I am able to access and create collections in both databases individually.

```
> use admin
> db.auth('user', 'password')
> db.copyDatabase('database1', 'database2')
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" }
```

Mongodb version is 2.4.5

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854898/mongodb-db-copydatabase-fail-on-unauthorized. looks like the same problem

Comment: but there is no solution there. If db size is too big then copying records for each collection will be terribly slow and error prone. Copying database on server through single command is what we need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one will not work currently.

There is a note in the source : at https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/cloner.cpp line 704
"Note: doesn't work with authentication enabled, except as old-style users."

Comment: Updating this for new-style auth is being tracked in [SERVER-8213](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8213) (currently slated for 2.6).

Comment: Thx than i update my comment at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854898/mongodb-db-copydatabase-fail-on-unauthorized

Answer (score -1):

you need logging in admin database for queries administrative, and her user need privileges in admin database